# Proof of the Dirac-$\gamma$ matrices identity

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, operators, proof

Given the matrices

$\gamma_{k}=\begin{bmatrix}
O & -i\sigma_{k}\\ 
 +i\sigma_{k}& O
\end{bmatrix}$

where $\sigma_{k}$ is the $k^{th}$ Pauli matrix

$\gamma_{4}=\begin{bmatrix}
I^{2} &0 \\ 
 0 & -I^{2} 
\end{bmatrix}$

$\gamma_{5}=\gamma_{1}.\gamma_{2}.\gamma_{3}.\gamma_{4}$

The anticommutator rule is defined by
$\left [ x,y \right ]=xy+yx$

Show that the anticommutator relation $\gamma_{u}.\gamma_{v}+\gamma_{v}.\gamma_{u}=2\delta _{u v}I$ is satisfied for all $u,v=1,2,3,4$
where $I$ is the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix.

What I have defined is

```
\[ScriptCapitalO] = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
Subscript[\[Gamma], 1] = {{\[ScriptCapitalO], -I PauliMatrix[1]},
                         {I PauliMatrix[1], \[ScriptCapitalO]}};

Subscript[\[Gamma], 2] = {{\[ScriptCapitalO], -I PauliMatrix[2]}, 
                        {I PauliMatrix[2], \[ScriptCapitalO]}};

Subscript[\[Gamma], 3] = {{\[ScriptCapitalO], -I PauliMatrix[3]},
                          {I PauliMatrix[3], \[ScriptCapitalO]}};

Subscript[\[Gamma], 4] = {{IdentityMatrix[2], \[ScriptCapitalO]}, 
                          {\[ScriptCapitalO], -IdentityMatrix[2]}};

Subscript[\[Gamma], 5] = 
 Subscript[\[Gamma], 1].Subscript[\[Gamma], 2].Subscript[\[Gamma],3].Subscript[\[Gamma], 4];
```

One way to do this would be to show the identity holds individually. But this would be tedious. Can someone help me with a more efficient and general way to this?

Comment: Are you aware of `ArrayFlatten[]`, BTW?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define `DiracMatrix`:

```
DiracMatrix[k_] /; k == 1 || k == 2 || k == 3 := 
  ArrayFlatten[{{0, - I PauliMatrix[k]}, {I PauliMatrix[k], 0}}]

DiracMatrix[4] := ArrayFlatten[{{ IdentityMatrix[2], 0}, {0, -IdentityMatrix[2]}}]

DiracMatrix[5] := Dot @@ Table[DiracMatrix[k], {k, 4}]
```

To prove the identity we could check e.g.

```
And @@ Flatten @ 
 Table[ DiracMatrix[i].DiracMatrix[k] + DiracMatrix[k].DiracMatrix[i]
        == 2 KroneckerDelta[i, k] IdentityMatrix[4], {i, 4}, {k, 4}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

sometimes one would prefer a visual test, something like e.g.

```
L[i_, k_] := DiracMatrix[i].DiracMatrix[k] + DiracMatrix[k].DiracMatrix[i] -
           2 KroneckerDelta[i, k] IdentityMatrix[4]
Table[ L[i, k] // MatrixForm, {i, 4}, {k, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: What is
`/; k == 1 || k == 2 || k == 3`
Supposed to mean?

Comment: This is Condition to ensure that the function DiracMatrix has appropriate values only for k equal to 1, 2, 3.  See Consdition at documentation pages.