# outer product of matrices

Tags: matrix

When I calculate the outer product of two matrices I get a correct result but the output is a matrix which has matrices as entries which is really annoying to deal with when I want to use it for further calculations later. For example:

```
a={{0,1},{1,0}};
Outer[Times,a,IdentityMatrix[2]]
```

while I would like to get directly the following output:

```
{{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0}}
```

Thank you

Comment: `KroneckerProduct[a, IdentityMatrix[2]]`?

Comment: I guess you are looking for `ArrayFlatten`, see e.g. [Proof of the Dirac-γ
matrices identity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/142146/proof-of-the-dirac-gamma-matrices-identity/142148#142148)

Answer (score 2):

```
KroneckerProduct[a, IdentityMatrix[2]]
```

> {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}}

Alternatively, as suggested by Artes in comments,

```
ArrayFlatten[Outer[Times, a, IdentityMatrix[2]]] == %
```

> True

Comment: Then `TensorProduct` is also helpful?

Comment: @AlexanderZeng, yes, great point.