# Unexpected result when evaluating DiracGamma[5]

Tags: matrix, feyncalc

```
ComplexConjugate[DiracGamma[5]] // StandardForm
```

returns

> ```
> -DiracGamma[5]
> ```

Instead of simply

> ```
> DiracGamma[5]
> ```

`DiracGamma[5]` is Hermitian is it not? Am I missing something?

Comment: In any case this is closely related [Proof of the Dirac-γ
matrices identity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/142146/proof-of-the-dirac-gamma-matrices-identity/142148#142148).

Comment: Not quite! I am addressing a specific issue with feyncalc functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ComplexConjugate` works on products of Dirac matrices assuming it is sandwiched between $u$ and/or $v$ spinors.  Observe:

```
SpinorUBar[k1, m].GA[5].SpinorU[p1, m] // ComplexConjugate
```

Output:

[image]

Now the minus sign makes sense.

Comment: Yeah I think I figured this out as well, because I get the correct expression at the end of the day when the gamma5 matrix is between two spinors.